# Folder permission issue with jarsigner

Tags: java, jar, jarsigner

This is definitely a very beginner question that might not have to do anything with programming. After few days, I have finally identified the problem as for why I couldn't sign jar using jarsigner. I kept getting this error that says "jarsigner: unable to create hello.jar.sig".

Basically, what I did was to put a jar in Java jdk's bin folder and then I shift-left click there in the folder to click on "Open the command window here". I generated the key from keytool and also used selfcert. Then when I did the jarsigner for a jar already put in the bin folder, I got the error. I eventually figured out the reason. I couldn't create the jar.sig in the bin folder since I don't have sort of permission. The question is, how do I set the destination to some folder that is modifiable?

I have no idea how to set the path to java directory and calling jarsigner from desktop or elsewhere, so I had to learn to write command prompt right inside the java bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move your JAR file to a directory you can read/write.
2. Run the original command:
   `"C:\Path\To\JDK\bin\jarsigner" [options] jar-file`

By default the output will be written to the directory you ran the command from.

In the long term, you can [add the JDK bin directory to your Windows path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path).